# Efficient solution for my task needed

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I just solve this but want know more efficient way to do matrix multiplication

```
 M = | 1 0 3 |
     | 1 0 2 |
     | 0 5 0 |
```

f[n] = M^n

I have implemented using [Exponentiation_by_squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Is there more efficient then this ?

Comment: @DavidPostill Why OT? Optimization and performance are common tags here.

Comment: I guess, this is actually more suitable for math as there's a closed form solution. Another posibility: You could speed up the program twice by deriving a formula for two steps. And this can be repeated...

Comment: @DavidPostill Others would send it to CR. It's all BS, if you ask me.

Comment: @maaartinus you are right i should have said codereview (not enough coffee)

Comment: @maaartinus `Others would send it to CR. It's all BS, if you ask me.` ?? what discussion going on .. can't get you

Comment: @ankit337 It's the strange idea that optimization problems belong to [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and whatever else belongs to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and whatever. It's all [BS](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=BS) as the distinction is pretty blurred and closing/downvoting questions based on such fuzzy criteria is unfriendly to newcommers. It also leads to many border cases with endless discussions. It wouldn't be so bad, if there was a simple way to *move* the question to another site (voting for move, etc.).

Comment: Okay i am going to delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, this is actually more suitable for math as there's a closed form solution. It's system of [Linear homogeneous recurrence relations with constant coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

Another posibility: You could speed up the program twice by deriving a formula for two steps, i.e., express `RR(i)` etc. via `RR(i-2)`, etc.

And this can be repeated, so you can jump much faster.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that your calculations are overflowing. If you run it for K=1 and J=9, you get `-334328541#510576792#-817751931`.
The easiest fix for that is to do `% 1000000006` in `calculateProduction`.

About efficiency, I would look at this problem as performing matrix multiplications.
You start with the vector (i.e. 1*3 matrix):

```
3 1 0
```

And at each step you multiply it (mod 1000000006) with the matrix:

```
1 1 0
0 0 5
3 2 0
```

Let's call the vector V and the matrix M. Basically you need to calculate V*M<sup>N</sup>. Since matrix multiplication is associative, you can calculate M<sup>N</sup> first, and do that recursively:
M<sup>N</sup> = (M<sup>N/2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> if N is even, or
M<sup>N</sup> = M*(M<sup>[N/2]</sup>)<sup>2</sup> if N is odd

Comment: i had also try that .. but did't get suggess

Comment: yes i already think this algo , but problem  matrix exponentiation may take time ..
Can you have better idea about matrix exponentiation algo ..(dynamic programming)

Comment: @ankit337 I already explained how to do matrix exponentiation easily, did you read the last part of my answer?

Comment: Yahh, I see , but i think that is not sufficient to improve performance , i get best way http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Teaching_Learning/Nth%20power%20of%20a%20square%20matrix.pdf , How to implement this ?

Comment: @ankit337 I'm pretty sure my method is good enough, it's logarithmic time

Comment: yes, I agree. But Implement this algo(matrix exponentiation) lead `stack overflow exception in JAVA`

Comment: @ankit337 That means you're doing it wrong. Maybe you forgot the base case of N=1?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate MM. This is why:

```
PP[i] = 5*MM[i-1] = 5*(RR[i-2] + 2*PP[i-2])
RR[i] = RR[i-1] + 3*PP[i-1] = (RR[i-2] + 3*PP[i-2]) + 3*PP[i-1]
```

See? You don't need to calculate MM at each step. This should be the algorithm:

```
public class RecurrenceMachine {
    private static final int max = 1000000006;

    public String calculate(int k, int j) {
        long n = k * j;
        if (n < 1)
            return "error";
        long RRi2 = 3;
        long PPi2 = 0;
        long RRi1 = 3 + 3 * PPi2;
        long PPi1 = 5 * 1;
        if (n == 1)
            return RRi1 + "##" + (RRi2 + 2 * PPi2) + "##" + PPi1;
        Long PPi = (long) 0, RRi = (long) 0, temp;
        int i;
        for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            temp = RRi2 + 2 * PPi2;
            PPi = 5 * temp;
            if (PPi >= max)
                PPi %= max;
            RRi = temp + PPi2 + 3 * PPi1;
            if (RRi >= max)
                RRi %= max;
            RRi2 = RRi1;
            PPi2 = PPi1;
            RRi1 = RRi;
            PPi1 = PPi;
        }
        return RRi + "##" + (RRi2 + 2 * PPi2) % max + "##" + PPi1;
    }
}
```

I tried only with small values and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for solution. you have improve code at one level but for large input its taking near to same time as mine code.

Comment: @ankit337 Can you give me some of those large inputs so I can try myself?

Comment: sure ..  here condition is `1<= K,J <= 10^6`
So you can take max from this as input

Comment: You're right. Even though the solution is faster, it doesn't work for very very large values. A different approach is needed.